# Found unexpected end of stream cloud-config

Tags: coreos, cloud-config

So this is my cloud-config

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  etcd2:
    discovery: "https://discovery.etcd.io/tocken"
    advertise-client-urls: "http://$private_ipv4:2379"
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: "http://$private_ipv4:2380"
    listen-client-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001"
    listen-peer-urls: "http://$private_ipv4:2380,http://$private_ipv4:7001"

  flannel:
    interface: $private_ipv4

  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
    - name: flanneld.service
      drop-ins:
        - name: 50-network-config.conf
          content: |
            [Service]
            ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{ "Network": "10.1.0.0/16" }'
      command: start
    - name: sshd.socket
      command: restart
      runtime: true
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=OpenSSH server daemon
        Conflicts=sshd.service

        [Socket]
        ListenStream=65321
        FreeBind=true
        Accept=yes

        [Install]
        WantedBy=sockets.target
    - name: kubelet.service
      command: restart
      runtime: true
      content: |
        [Service]
        Environment=KUBELET_VERSION=v1.6.1_coreos.0
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
        ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
          --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 \
          --allow-privileged=true \
          --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
          --hostname-override=$private_ipv4 \
          --cluster-dns=10.13.0.10 \
          --cluster-domain=cluster.local
        Restart=always
        RestartSec=10

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

users:
  - name: admin
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuCXgeT7kQfSikcU1BWRyMFi8izN+1WHPNopaaXQV2xune6nKOHN8yhGVRKaE9iQHY+6jSjxWd5SY9CEyWlIST5dxfffRkWZiuJISHAxl6+E+fI0kNsUG2AXTXuJnXBQllqkgsggfBJ+5BxNf35IyfILTqkDu99ZNBNbeTNSPJmbYgMs71fWB2TiGx8ugsZrIOzqbcEfu9KNTD+RszrLaCRAZNl1sANEk7N7ZIUaIIlBBxmaPWW1voXor4AP/SAnHMEouX25ZlruL7nCEH9BybVYT8xFVEBl0fJIoj/c1TYkk/80P7JLJg0pIAxMCWqy0NzBwEcXbef1yIlO6meDuZ Kirill@NOUTKIR
    groups:
     - "sudo"
    shell: /bin/bash
write_files:
  - path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    permissions: 0600
    owner: root:root
    content: |
         HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
         HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
         HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
         HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
         UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
         KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
         ServerKeyBits 1024
         SyslogFacility AUTH
         LogLevel INFO
         LoginGraceTime 120
         PermitRootLogin no
         StrictModes yes
         RSAAuthentication yes
         PubkeyAuthentication yes
         IgnoreRhosts yes
         RhostsRSAAuthentication no
         HostbasedAuthentication no
         PermitEmptyPasswords no
         ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
         X11Forwarding yes
         X11DisplayOffset 10
         PrintMotd no
         PrintLastLog yes
         TCPKeepAlive yes
         AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
         Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
         UsePAM yes
         AllowUsers admin
         PasswordAuthentication no
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
#    permissions: ??
#    owner: ??
    content: |
         apiVersion: v1
         kind: Pod
         metadata:
           name: kube-apiserver
           namespace: kube-system
         spec:
           hostNetwork: true
           containers:
           - name: kube-apiserver
             image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0
             command:
             - /hyperkube
             - apiserver
             - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
             - --etcd-servers=http://<master private IP>:2379,http://<node1 private IP>:2379,http://<node2 private IP>:2379
             - --allow-privileged=true
             - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.13.0.0/24
             - --secure-port=443
             - --advertise-address=<master private IP>
             - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota
#    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
#    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
#    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
             - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
             - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1=true,extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true
             ports:
             - containerPort: 443
               hostPort: 443
               name: https
             - containerPort: 8080
               hostPort: 8080
               name: local
#    volumeMounts:
#    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
#      name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
#      readOnly: true
#    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
#      name: ssl-certs-host
#      readOnly: true
#  volumes:
#  - hostPath:
#      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
#    name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
#  - hostPath:
#      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
#    name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml
#    permissions: ??
#    owner: ??
    content: |
         apiVersion: v1
         kind: Pod
         metadata:
           name: kube-proxy
           namespace: kube-system
         spec:
           hostNetwork: true
           containers:
           - name: kube-proxy
             image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0
             command:
             - /hyperkube
             - proxy
             - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
             - --proxy-mode=iptables
             securityContext:
               privileged: true
#             volumeMounts:
#             - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
#               name: ssl-certs-host
#               readOnly: true
#           volumes:
#           - hostPath:
#               path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
#             name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
#    permissions: ??
#    owner: ??
    content: |
         apiVersion: v1
         kind: Pod
         metadata:
           name: kube-controller-manager
           namespace: kube-system
         spec:
           hostNetwork: true
           containers:
           - name: kube-controller-manager
             image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0
             command:
             - /hyperkube
             - controller-manager
             - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
             - --leader-elect=true
#             - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
#             - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
             livenessProbe:
               httpGet:
                 host: 127.0.0.1
                 path: /healthz
                 port: 10252
               initialDelaySeconds: 15
               timeoutSeconds: 1
#             volumeMounts:
#             - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
#               name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
#               readOnly: true
#             - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
#               name: ssl-certs-host
#               readOnly: true
#           volumes:
#           - hostPath:
#               path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
#             name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
#           - hostPath:
#               path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
#             name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
#    permissions: ??
#    owner: ??
    content: |
         apiVersion: v1
         kind: Pod
         metadata:
           name: kube-scheduler
           namespace: kube-system
         spec:
           hostNetwork: true
           containers:
           - name: kube-scheduler
             image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0
             command:
             - /hyperkube
             - scheduler
             - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
             - --leader-elect=true
             livenessProbe:
               httpGet:
                 host: 127.0.0.1
                 path: /healthz
                 port: 10251
               initialDelaySeconds: 15
               timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Anyone face this before? I already lost 4 hours googling and trying shit

P.S: Error on prelast line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 99:

```
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

...is missing a quote.

FYI I found this in about 5 seconds with the help of [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/).